# What is the correct way to use typeclass syntax when you have a typeclass within a typeclass?

Tags: scala, inner-classes, typeclass, implicit

I have a situation where I am using a typeclass-within-a-typeclass in order to overload methods of the original typeclass. Example below:

```
abstract class IsArray[A, T: Numeric] {
  def getSingleElem(self: A, idx: Int): T
  def getRef[R](self: A, ref: R)(implicit refTc: RefTC[R]): refTc.Out = refTc.getRef(self, ref)

  trait RefTC[R] {
    type Out
    def getRef(self: A, ref: R): Out
  }
  object RefTC {
    implicit val numsTcForSingleInt = new RefTC[Int] {
      type Out = T
      def getRef(self: A, ref: Int): Out = getSingleElem(self, ref)
    }
    implicit val numsTcForListInt = new RefTC[List[Int]] {
      type Out = List[T]
      def getRef(self: A, ref: List[Int]): Out = ref.map(getSingleElem(self, _))
    }
  }
}
```

This all works fine. Where I am having difficulties is in creating a 'syntax' object for the typeclass, so the methods can be called directly from values that implement the typeclass. My first attempt looks like this and type-checks OK:

```
object IsArraySyntax {
  implicit class IsArrayOps1[A, T: Numeric](self: A)(implicit isArTc: IsArray[A, T]) {
    def getSingleElem(idx: Int): T = isArTc.getSingleElem(self, idx)
    def getRef[R](ref: R)(implicit refTc: isArTc.RefTC[R]): refTc.Out = refTc.getRef(self, ref)
  }
}
```

However, I've been getting some strange errors whilst using this (eg [java.lang.NoSuchFieldError when using ScalaTest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63975061/java-lang-nosuchfielderror-when-using-scalatest)) and I'm wondering if the way I'm writing this is to blame. There is effectively a dependency between the `isArTc` typeclass and the refTc typeclass, which becomes an explicit dependency if the `isArTc` typeclass is a parameter of the method rather than than of the `IsArrayOps1` class, likeso:

```
object IsArraySyntax {
  implicit class IsArrayOps2[A, T: Numeric](self: A) {
    def getSingleElem(idx: Int)(implicit isArTc: IsArray[A, T]): T = isArTc.getSingleElem(self, idx)
    def getRef[R](ref: R)(implicit isArTc: IsArray[A, T], refTc: isArTc.RefTC[R]): refTc.Out = refTc.getRef(self, ref)
  }
}
```

This does not type check and presumably requires the `Aux` pattern to be made to work.

But I was more wondering what is best practice here? Having the `isArTc` typeclass as a property of the `implicit class` rather than each method seems to reduce boilerplate and simplify typeclass dependencies, but I've not seen it used and I was wondering if it was undesirable for some other reason? And is `refTc: isArTc.RefTC[R]` the correct syntax for a typeclass belonging to another typeclass, or should it be something more like `refTc: IsArray#RefTC[R]`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nested type classes are used rarer but in principle they can be used.

Another example of nested type class is [How to avoid calling asInstanceOf in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62716323/how-to-avoid-calling-asinstanceof-in-scala)

> This does not type check and presumably requires the `Aux` pattern to be made to work.

No, `Aux` pattern will not help. `Aux` pattern helps with dependencies in type parameters/type members but can't help with depedencies in prefixes like in `IsArrayOps2`. Such kind of dependency just can't be expressed in Scala 2.

Actually, splitting implicit parameters into class-level and method-level ones (like in `IsArrayOps1`) is correct way to fight with such kind of dependency.

> should it be something more like `refTc: IsArray#RefTC[R]`?

No, type projections don't play well with implicit resolution

https://typelevel.org/blog/2015/07/23/type-projection.html

You can check that with type projections your syntax will not work.

> I've been getting some strange errors whilst using this (eg java.lang.NoSuchFieldError when using ScalaTest) and I'm wondering if the way I'm writing this is to blame.

Your type classes and syntax #1 seem to work

```
case class MyClass(is: List[Int])
object MyClass {
  implicit val mcIsIntArray: IsArray[MyClass, Int] = new IsArray[MyClass, Int] {
    override def getSingleElem(self: MyClass, idx: Int): Int = self.is(idx)
  }
  implicit val mcIsDoubleArray: IsArray[MyClass, Double] = new IsArray[MyClass, Double] {
    override def getSingleElem(self: MyClass, idx: Int): Double = self.is(idx)
  }
}

val ia = implicitly[IsArray[MyClass, Int]]
implicitly[ia.RefTC[Int] { type Out = Int}]
implicitly[ia.RefTC[List[Int]] { type Out = List[Int]}]
val ia1 = implicitly[IsArray[MyClass, Double]]
implicitly[ia1.RefTC[Int] { type Out = Double}]
implicitly[ia1.RefTC[List[Int]] { type Out = List[Double]}]

implicitly[IsArray[MyClass, Int]].getSingleElem(MyClass(List(1, 2, 3)), 1) // 2
implicitly[IsArray[MyClass, Int]].getRef(MyClass(List(1, 2, 3)), 1) // 2
implicitly[IsArray[MyClass, Int]].getRef(MyClass(List(1, 2, 3)), List(1, 0)) // List(2, 1)
implicitly[IsArray[MyClass, Double]].getSingleElem(MyClass(List(1, 2, 3)), 1) // 2.0
implicitly[IsArray[MyClass, Double]].getRef(MyClass(List(1, 2, 3)), 1) // 2.0 
implicitly[IsArray[MyClass, Double]].getRef(MyClass(List(1, 2, 3)), List(1, 0)) // List(2.0, 1.0)

import IsArraySyntax._
{
  import Numeric.IntIsIntegral // to avoid ambiguity
  MyClass(List(1, 2, 3)).getSingleElem(1): Int
  MyClass(List(1, 2, 3)).getRef(1): Int
  MyClass(List(1, 2, 3)).getRef(List(1, 0)): List[Int]
}

{
  import Numeric.DoubleIsFractional // to avoid ambiguity
  MyClass(List(1, 2, 3)).getSingleElem(1): Double
  MyClass(List(1, 2, 3)).getRef(1): Double
  MyClass(List(1, 2, 3)).getRef(List(1, 0)): List[Double]
}
```

I imported implicits `Numeric.IntIsIntegral`, `Numeric.DoubleIsFractional` to corresponding scopes to avoid ambiguity like in [Implicit view not working - is my implicit def to blame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63964610/implicit-view-not-working-is-my-implicit-def-to-blame)

By the way, you can express the same logic with a single type class adding more type parameters and conditional implicits (`listIsArray`)

```
abstract class IsArray[A, T: Numeric, R, Out] {
  def getRef(self: A, ref: R): Out
}
trait LowPriorityIsArray {
  implicit def listIsArray[A, T: Numeric, R, Out](implicit
    singleIsArray: IsArray[A, T, R, Out]
  ): IsArray[A, T, List[R], List[Out]] = new IsArray[A, T, List[R], List[Out]] {
    override def getRef(self: A, ref: List[R]): List[Out] =
      ref.map(singleIsArray.getRef(self, _))
  }
}
object IsArray extends LowPriorityIsArray {
  implicit val mcIsIntArray: IsArray[MyClass, Int, Int, Int] = new IsArray[MyClass, Int, Int, Int] {
    override def getRef(self: MyClass, idx: Int): Int = self.is(idx)
  }
  implicit val mcIsDoubleArray: IsArray[MyClass, Double, Int, Double] = new IsArray[MyClass, Double, Int, Double] {
    override def getRef(self: MyClass, idx: Int): Double = self.is(idx)
  }
}

object IsArraySyntax {
  implicit class IsArrayOps3[A, T: Numeric, R, Out](self: A) {
    def getSingleElem(idx: Int)(implicit 
      isAr: IsArray[A, T, R, Out], 
      ev: Int <:< R
    ): Out = isAr.getRef(self, idx)
    def getRef(ref: R)(implicit isAr: IsArray[A, T, R, Out]): Out =
      isAr.getRef(self, ref)
  }
}
    
case class MyClass(is: List[Int])

import IsArraySyntax._
{
  import Numeric.IntIsIntegral
  MyClass(List(1, 2, 3)).getSingleElem(1): Int
  MyClass(List(1, 2, 3)).getRef(1): Int
  MyClass(List(1, 2, 3)).getRef(List(1, 0)): List[Int]
}

{
  import Numeric.DoubleIsFractional
  MyClass(List(1, 2, 3)).getSingleElem(1): Double
  MyClass(List(1, 2, 3)).getRef(1): Double
  MyClass(List(1, 2, 3)).getRef(List(1, 0)): List[Double]
}
```

Notice that syntax

```
object IsArraySyntax {
  implicit class IsArrayOps4[A, T: Numeric, R, Out](self: A)(implicit
    isAr: IsArray[A, T, R, Out]
  ) {
    def getSingleElem(idx: Int)(implicit ev: Int <:< R): Out =
      isAr.getRef(self, idx)
    def getRef(ref: R): Out = isAr.getRef(self, ref)
  }
}
```

will not work.

Or you can make `Out` a type member rather than type parameter.

Well, I've just noticed that I actually didn't use `T` in my type class, so probably that's not what you wanted. You can try a single higher-kinded type class

```
abstract class IsArray[A, T: Numeric, Col[_], R <: Col[T], Out] {
  def getRef(self: A, ref: R): Out
}
```

or just

```
abstract class IsArray[A, T: Numeric, Col[_], Out] {
  def getRef(self: A, ref: Col[T]): Out
}
```

Here in our instances `Col` can be `Id` or `List`.